# How to get data from one form to another in C#

Tags: c#, forms

My function is loading picture from selected folder. Now i want to zoom this picture by opening it in new form - ZoomLogo. In this new form, i'd like to 'get' fullPath1 from my main form, and then load picture using this path in form ZoomLogo.. How to do it?

```
void Picture()
{
```

...

```
    if (DataBaseSelection.SelectedIndex+1==1) 
    {
    Logo1_pictureBox.Image=new Bitmap(@"Logos\\aa.bmp");
     var file1 = Path.ChangeExtension(Printer2_TextBox.Text, ".jpg");
    var fullPath1 = Path.Combine(@"Documents\\Base\\", file1);
    if (!File.Exists(fullPath1))
    {
    MessageBox.Show("No picture!");
    }
     else
    {
       Logo_pictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(fullPath1);
    }
```

...

```
}
```

Open new form:

```
    void ZoomPictureBoxClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ZoomSchematic settings = new ZoomSchematic();
        settings.ShowDialog();          
    }
```

I was trying to use something like that in my main form:

```
    void ZoomPictureBoxClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ZoomSchematic settings = new ZoomSchematic(this.fullPath1);
        settings.ShowDialog();          
    }
```

but i don't know how to get this variable from function Picture()..

Comment: Do you need to get the specified settings from the ZoomSchematic dialog ?

Comment: All i need is fullPath1, so I can display picture using this location path. ZoomSchematic dialog contains only 1 picturebox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make `fullPath1` a member field of your main form.

```
 class MainForm
 {
     private string fullPath1;

     void Picture()
     {
        if (DataBaseSelection.SelectedIndex+1==1) 
        {
           Logo1_pictureBox.Image=new Bitmap(@"Logos\\aa.bmp");
           var file1 = Path.ChangeExtension(Printer2_TextBox.Text, ".jpg");
           fullPath1 = Path.Combine(@"Documents\\Base\\", file1);
           if (!File.Exists(fullPath1))
           {
              MessageBox.Show("No picture!");
           }
           else
           {
              Logo_pictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(fullPath1);
           }
        }
      }

     void ZoomPictureBoxClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         ZoomSchematic settings = new ZoomSchematic(this.fullPath1);
         settings.ShowDialog();          
     }
 }

 class ZoomSchematic
 {   
     string _fullPath1;

     public ZoomSchematic(string fullPath1)
     {
        _fullPath1 = fullPath1;
     }
 }
```

Comment: I'm getting error: Error CS1729: 'App.ZoomSchematic' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Comment: Is this a correct place for putting this class?: namespace App
{
 class ZoomSchematic{...}
 public partial class MainForm : Form {..} cause i'm getting error: The item "obj\x86\Release\App.ZoomSchematic.resources" was specified more than once in the "Resources" parameter.  Duplicate items are not supported by the "Resources" parameter.

Comment: NO! it was just an example. Maybe you need to get back to basics and check out some C# books: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46048/what-is-the-best-book-to-learn-c

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually going to zoom in, why not send the picture rather than reload the picture? Eg,

```
void ZoomPictureBoxClick(Bitmap zoomthis)
{
...
}
```

as this will be within your form still, eg

```
ZoomSchematic settings = new ZoomSchematic(Logo_pictureBox.Image)
```

It depends a little on what you want to do with it once there, if you were just going to show the settings, I guess it depends why you need the path.

Bit of a vauge answer, but I feel the question was open to more questions.

If you need the path to send on later, then when you make your Bitmap, you could/should keep hold of the path. Rather than a local variable.

Comment: ZoomSchematic settings = new ZoomSchematic(Logo_pictureBox.Image);
settings.ShowDialog(); and i'm gettin error: Error CS1729: 'App.ZoomSchematic' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments. ZoomSchematic is created form by me btw.

Comment: OK, then you need to create the constructor that allows for a parameter thats why its complaining

Answer (score 0):

use form constructor to pass the file path

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(string path);
Form2.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what `Picture()` does and for what it is called ... if picture delivers more than one picture to your main form you will have to sort out which is the picture in question ...

if it is only one picture, you could simply add a new private string member fullpath1 to your form, which will have to be set everytime `Picture()` is called ...